# ActivatedRoute observable with manual refresh ability

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I'm currently developing an Angular component that needs manual "re-fetch from server" functionality.

The version listed below works but is there any way to simplify it? It looks a bit complicated.

```js
private refreshSignalSubject = new Subject<any>();
refreshSignal$: Observable<any> = this.refreshSignalSubject.asObservable();

ngOnInit() {
  this.item$ = combineLatest(
    this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      map(params => params.get('id')),
    ),
    this.refreshSignal$.pipe(
      startWith(() => Math.random())
    )
  ).pipe(
    map((values) => {
      const [id, _] = values
      return id
    }),
    switchMap(id => this.apiService.get(`/items/${id}`)),
    share()
  )
}

reloadItem() { // this method is triggered from the view and from other methods in this component
  this.refreshSignalSubject.next(Math.random());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't even need to put it in `ngOnInit`:

```ts
readonly items$ = combineLatest([
  this.route.params.pipe(
    map(({ id }) => id),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  ),
  this.refreshSignal$
]).pipe(
  switchMap(([ id ]) => this.apiService.get(`/items/${id}`)),
  shareReplay(1)
)
```

This should be enough

Comment: I had to add `startWith` to the `refreshSignal$`, otherwise is looks good. Thank you

Comment: @NikitaFedyashev: Why not make `refreshSignalSubject` a `BehaviorSubject` in that case? That would mitigate the need for `startWith`.

Comment: @NikitaFedyashev as Michael said to use a `BehaviorSubject`. Or you can call `reloadItem()` in `ngOnInit`